# How to convert datatype in Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have two tables and I am trying to perform the following tasks:

1. Table A: The column "Number" of this table contains duplicates. Find the most recent entry of
   each duplicate by finding the highest ID of the duplicate. For example, Number:1 had ID: 1,4,and 6. Choose Number 1 with ID 6.
2. Inner JOIN Table A and Table B ON "Number".

The data type of A.Number is Short Text and B.Number is Double. I tried to use CDbl() to overcome the problem but Access kept returning the "Data type mismatch" error. Please help!

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & _
            "(SELECT * FROM tableA as A Where A.ID in " & _
            "(SELECT MAX(C.ID) As maxID FROM tableA as C WHERE C.Number > '0' GROUP BY C.Number)) as tblClean " & _
            "INNER JOIN tblB As B ON (CDbl(tblClean.Number) = B.Number)"
```

Comment: This is a type mismatch in your query: `WHERE C.Number > '0'`

Comment: Oops sorry ignore ^

Comment: It is generally very very bad to store numbers as doubles and then treat them like integers - are your numbers really numbers like 1.2334, 4.4433, 6.5544 or are they numbers like 1, 4, 6 ... 

Floats are extremely difficult to compare with precision, or likewise to group effectively.

Comment: It is also possible there is a value (or nulls?) in tableA number column that aren't actually numbers so can't convert.

Comment: @topsail They are all integer-like. For example, "50023". I verified that all values were not null and were nominal. I ran the statement without the INNER JOIN and it worked fine.

Comment: @topsail Clarification: I ran the type conversion without the INNER JOIN and it worked without errors.

Comment: Its generally not easy or recommendable to do equality on floats - because what looks like 1 = 1 might really be 1.000000000000001 = 1 and be false, not true. Do you have some sample data from these tables so that me (or someone else) can gin up a working example to mess about with?

Comment: You might want to implement rounding in the solution, or casting to integers, or even a basic text representation that you can control - to be sure you are always comparing apples to apples.

Comment: @topsail I found a work around by first converting the column from string to int and storing the converted data in a new column. Then, I used that column in the query and got it to work as expected. For the comparison point you made, I'd expect the program to skip over the false rows instead of throwing an error?

Comment: Yes, that is correct - in regard to the comparison point I made, you would have a "false"  for the where criteria so it would just skip over those rows.